# Using bufferedreader to read a file and store Strings and ints

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I want to read a txt file (parameters.txt) that looks like this:

```
1 
5
8
wa
wb
```

This is my code to iterate through it:

```
private void storeCacheParams() {
        try {

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(parameters));
            int cache = reader.read();
            if ( cache == 1 ) {
                cacheType = "direct-mapped";
            } else if ( cache == 2 ){
                cacheType = "2-way set associative";
            }

            offsetBits = reader.read();
            indexBits = reader.read();
            allPol = reader.readLine();
            writePol = reader.readLine();

            System.out.println("Cache: " + cacheType);
            System.out.println("Offset Bits: " + offsetBits);
            System.out.println("Index Bits: " + indexBits);
            System.out.println("Allocation Policy: " + allPol);
            System.out.println("Write Policy: " + writePol);

        } catch (IOException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I am storing each line that I read into a variable that is either an int or a String. Here are my variables declarations:

```
private String cacheType;
    private int offsetBits;
    private int indexBits;
    private String allPol;
    private String writePol;
```

The problem is that this prints out:

```
Cache: 2-way set associative
Offset Bits: 13
Index Bits: 10
Allocation Policy: 5
Write Policy: 8
```

But the offset bits should be 5, the index bits should be 8, the allPol should be wa, and writePol should be wb. Where is my program getting the 13 and the 10 from?

Comment: Put your parameters all on the same line or (alternatively) use `reader.readLine();`

Comment: 10 - Line Feed, 13 - Carriage Return. See [ASCII table](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-control-characters/line-feed-ascii-code-10.html).

Comment: This is for a project where the professor tests my code with many different "parameters.txt" files, so I do not have control of the format of it. What do you mean reader.readLine? I am doing that for my String type variables, but how would I go about doing that with the ints?